# can you obtain values of variables within a method which is in a class from another class?

Tags: c#, methods, view

I'm very  new to c# and Im stuck within trying to obtain values of a variable inside a method which is in a particular class from another class .

For example 
Lets say Class A has a method `setPath ();` which has a variable called string `rootpath = "something";`

can I acess this variable rootPath from another class ; Class B ?!

Any Help is Really Appreciated

Comment: Why do not declare it outside the method?

Comment: Because I need to use it specifically inside the method

Comment: You can `return` that value from the method. Or you can pass it to a `ref` or `out` paramter if it is really neccesary.

Comment: I think thats a good appraoch , can you show me a slight implementation of it if possible

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `return` that value from the method. Or you can pass it to a `ref` or `out` paramter if it is really neccesary.

```
  //your official method
  void setPath()
  {
    string rootPath = "Something";
  }

  // you can return a string
  string setPathByReturn()
  {
    string rootPath = "Something";
    return rootPath;
  }

  //or pass it to an out paramter
  void setPathByOut(out string str)
  {
    string rootPath = "Something";
    str = rootPath;
  }

  //or pass it to a reference
  void setPathByRef(ref string str)
  {
    string rootPath = "Something";
    str = rootPath;
  }
```

A thing you should take attention, if you pass string by a `ref` parameter, the varaible should be initialized before.

**Example of usage:**

```
string striWithOut;
setPathByOut(out striWithOut);

string strWithRef = "";
setPathByRef(ref strWithRef);
```

You can read more about `ref` and `out` paramter pass at MSDN.

- [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref)
- [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier)

Comment: after this how do I pass it out ?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: But still str is inside the method ryt ? how do I pass it out

Comment: I don't understand. ryt?

Comment: right* = ryt 
Im asking how to take that variable outside that method

Comment: There are two example for use `out` and `ref` keyword. Isn't it clear?

Comment: Will look into it more 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Your welcome sir. Btw. I put two hyperlinks if you would like to read about `ref` and `out` keyword on official Microsoft documentation.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. One way to accomplish this would be to make the variable a public property of your class. See the following example:

```
class A {
    public string rootpath { get; private set; }

    public void setPath()
    {
        this.rootpath = "something";
    }
}
```

Now it is possible to access the property from another class using `instanceOfA.rootpath` (while `instanceOfA` is an instance of your class `A`)